# Determine the number of permutations of $ \ \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \ $ that have exactly 3 numbers in their natural position

Tags: permutations

**Determine the number of permutations of $ \  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \  $  that have exactly  3 numbers in their natural position.** $$ $$ Is it $ \ \ \begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} \times 7 ! \  $ ?

Comment: The answer is no, because some of those $7!$ orderings will put additional numbers in their natural position.

Answer (score 2):

No, because $7!$ allows for extra elements to be in their natural position.  After the $3$ fixed position items are selected, you need a derangement of the remaining $7$ items.

Comment: would you help a little more doing this problem? Thanks

Comment: @mabmath You can just read about derangements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 1):

You need choose $3$ elements that stay on their positions in $\binom{10}{3} = 120$ and multiply it by the number $!7$ of permutations of special kind called [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on remaining $7$ elements. There are many ways to compute number $!k$ (see link), particularly it is known to be equal to $\frac{k!}{e}$ rounded to the nearest integer. Therefore $\frac{5040}{e} \approx 1854 =\,!7$ and the desired number of permutations on $10!$ elements keeping exactly $3$ of them in place is $\binom{10}{3} \cdot\,!7 = 120 \cdot 1854 = 222\,480$.

---

Another way to compute number of such permutation is [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html). There are $\binom{10}{3}\cdot 7!$ ways to select $3$ elements to stay in place and permute all remaining. But for each of $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select $4$ elements each permutation that keeps them in place was computed $4$ times, but should not be computed at all. Continuing these thoughts we get that the right number of desired permutations is
$$\binom{10}{3}\cdot 7! - \binom{10}{4} \cdot 6! \cdot \binom{4}{3} + \binom{10}{5} \cdot 5! \cdot \binom{5}{3} - \binom{10}{6} \cdot 4! \cdot \binom{6}{3}\\
 + \binom{10}{7} \cdot 3! \cdot \binom{7}{3} - \binom{10}{8} \cdot 2! \cdot \binom{8}{3} + \binom{10}{9} \cdot 1! \cdot \binom{9}{3} - \binom{10}{10} \cdot 0! \cdot \binom{10}{3}\\
 = 604800 - 604800 + 302400 - 100800 + 25200 - 5040 + 840 - 120 = 222480.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{n}{3}[!(n-3)]$ where $n=10$ and $$!k = k! \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The number of permutations in $S_{10}$ which have exactly $3$ fixed points is ${10 \choose 3} \times D_7$, where $D_7$ denotes the number of permutations of a $7$-element set which contain no fixed points (the number $D_7$ of derangements in $S_7$ can be computed using the principle of inclusion-exclusion).